# Derive a bool column based on groupby with current row compared to previous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to calculate a row number over several groups where the number increments only if the current row has different classification values vs. the previous.

I'm thinking calculating a boolean series per group then calling `cumsum()` on that would give me what I need (though I've no doubt there may be a better way).

My test dataset looks like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id_1": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "id_2": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
    "class_1": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    "class_2": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2] 
})
```

| id_1 | id_2 | class_1 | class_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 |

I would like to group on the `id` columns and compare the `classification` columns.

So far I have:

```py
df["t_id"] = df.groupby(['id_1', 'id_2'], as_index=False)['class_1'].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum())
df
```

which produces the correct output shown below:

| id_1 | id_2 | class_1 | class_2 | t_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 | 3 |

However this only compares each value in the `class_1` column to the previous row's value.  I can't fathom how to include the `class_2` as part of the comparisons.  I was hoping it would be something like the following, but alas this doesn't work!

```py
df["t_id"] = df.groupby(["id_1", "id_2"], as_index=False)["class_1", "class_2"].apply(lambda x: ((x["class_1"] != x["class_2"].shift()) or (x["class_2"] != x["class_2"].shift())).cumsum())
df
```

Here is the expected result I'm looking for when considering both the `class_` and `class_2` columns:

| id_1 | id_2 | class_1 | class_2 | t_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | a | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | a | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 | 2 | 3 |

I'm using Python 1.8 and Pandas 1.5.3 (although I might need to target Pandas 0.22.1).

Advice welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a few ways of doing it, but to fix the approach you took, instead of `x["class_2"].shift()` you needed to do `x.shift()["class_2"]`:

```
df['t_id'] = df.groupby(['id_1', 'id_2'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: ((x['class_1'] != x.shift()['class_1']) | (x['class_2'] != x.shift()['class_2'])).cumsum()).reset_index()[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id_1 id_2  class_1  class_2  t_id
0     1    a        1        1     1
1     1    a        1        1     1
2     1    a        1        2     2
3     2    a        1        1     1
4     2    a        1        2     2
5     2    a        1        2     2
6     2    b        2        2     1
7     2    b        1        1     2
8     2    b        2        2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: compare tuples made of the multiple columns:

```py
def fn(x):
    t = x[["class_1", "class_2"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)
    return (t != t.shift()).cumsum()


df["t_id"] = df.groupby(["id_1", "id_2"], group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id_1 id_2  class_1  class_2  t_id
0     1    a        1        1     1
1     1    a        1        1     1
2     1    a        1        2     2
3     2    a        1        1     1
4     2    a        1        2     2
5     2    a        1        2     2
6     2    b        2        2     1
7     2    b        1        1     2
8     2    b        2        2     3
```